# Can a source map be called from another site

Tags: javascript, minify, source-maps

I am using a source map from a library's minified JavaScript to the full fat JavaScript. This is all being done locally like so:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=index.min.js.map
```

It occurred to me that as the library is hosted on GitHub it would be simpler to link to the raw source map in the repo:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foo-user/bar-project/master/release/index.min.js.map
```

Would this work and what would the drawbacks be of this approach (e.g. versioning, availability)?

Comment: I guess dev-tools will always fetch the version from master branch

Comment: Thanks @Vizz85 that is my guess too. I'm wondering if anyone had any experience of implementing this and if there are any gotchas when debugging any particular browsers.